# include data from one table to attachment in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I need show avatar from user in posts list, in "show" avatar work.

Controller

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
  @user = User.find(@post.user_id)
end
```

View
index.html.haml

```
= render @posts
```

_post.html.haml

```
= @user.avatar.url(:thumb)
= post.title
= post.body
```

Comment: Are you using `Active Storage`?

Comment: use carrierwave and mini_magick

Comment: where are you defining `@post` ? in the index action?

Comment: Its final version of controller, i definite it like this `@post.find(params[:id])`

Comment: Try with `= image_tag post.user.avatar.url(:thumb)` instead of `= @user.avatar.url(:thumb)`

Comment: i have this error `undefined method `avatar?' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just need to use `= image_tag post.user.avatar.url(:thumb)`

Answer (score 0):

you need the [image_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag) to display the image

change `= @user.avatar.url(:thumb)` to `= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb)`

Comment: i have this error undefined method avatar?' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: check if @user returns a user record. Else put the above statement in If else block checking `@user!= nil`

Comment: user return nil, how to call user.id form post.user_id?

Comment: if `@post` points to a single post and the relationship between post and user exists, i.e `belongs_to :user`, then you can call `@post.user_id` if the user_id column exists in post model. Else try `@post.user.id`

Comment: i have relationship, but it return `undefined method "user_id" for nil:NilClass`, i called `posts` but not define `post`, i cant give id to `@post = Post.find(params[:id])`

Comment: I find answere, i just need to call in view `= image_tag post.user.avatar.url(:thumb)`